# Install an sql dump file to a docker container with mariaDB

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I am just learning the basics of docker, but have come stuck on importing an SQl file from the local system. I am on windows 10 and have allowed my docker containers to access my shared drives. I have an SQL file located on D i would like to import to the base image of Maria DB i got from docker hub.

I have found a command to install that sql file on my image and tried to directly import the image from inside the container sql command prompt, but get a failed to open file error.

Below are the two methods i have tried, but where do i store my sql dump and how do i import it?

**Method 1** tried via mysql command line

```
winpty docker run -it --link *some-mariadb*:mysql --rm mariadb sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"'
```

Then

```
use *database-created* // previously created
```

Then

```
source d:/sql_dump_file.sql
```

**Method 2**

```
docker exec -i my-new-database mysql -uroot -pnew-db-password --force < d:/sql_dump_file.sql
```

**Update 5/12/2016**

So after a disappointing weekend of playing around. I currently change the drive to C: drive as there seemed to be some unknown issue i can't debug with getting D: drive to work.

Then i found the inspect command to see what volumes are mounted to a container. I have the following, but i can't import to SQL as it says file does not exist, but it clearly says in docker that it is there and mounted, the SQL file is inside the map_me folder. I created a folder called map_me in the main directory of C:

```
docker inspect dbcontainer

       "Mounts": 
           [
            {
                "Source": "/map_me",
                "Destination": "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sl_dump_fil‌​e.sql",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
           ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some tweaking and better understanding, i came to the conclusion after testing, that docker-compose is the way to go. So the first folder contains a my.cnf file that does the configuration, then the other folder which @Farhad identified is used to intilize the .sql file.

```
version: "2"

services:

    mariadb_a:
        image: mariadb:latest
        ports: 
         - "3306:3306"
        environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=111111
        volumes:
         - c:/some_folder:/etc/mysql/conf.d
         - c:/some_other_folder:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the following:

Mount your `sql_dump_file.sql` at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` when creating the container. The official MariaDB image will restore it at startup.

```
docker run -d --name <containername> -v d:/sql_dump_file.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sl_dump_file.sql <environment_variables> <imagename> <startup commands>
```

Comment: it created the image file, but when i went into the sql, it just has the default mysql tables.

Comment: try this one: `docker run -d --name <containername> -v d:\sql_dump_file.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sl_dump_file.sql <environment_variables> <imagename> <startup commands>`

Comment: Same thing again, creates a database with standard MySQL config, but my SQL dump is not there.

Comment: Is there an easier way or another way of doing this?

Comment: the basics are correct, the rest is windows problem, pathing. try enabling file and printer sharing.

Comment: The extra colon in `-v` sounds problematic.  The use of `\` in a *nix environment seems wrong also.

Comment: @farhad, so after understanding the filesystem inside docker more, sorry not a linux background. it does mount and i can see it, but my sql won't execute it

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: This kinda works, but make sure that this is based on a windows system. Would be nicer to have seen the answer inside a docker-compose but it's a good answer non the less