# How do I restore a dump file from mysqldump using kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, mariadb

I know [how to restore a dump file from mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/105776/232794). Now, I am attempting to do that using kubernetes and a docker container. The database files are in persistent (nfs) mount. The docker cannot be accessed outside of the cluster as there is no need for anything external to touch it.

I tried:

```
kubectl run -i -t dbtest --image=mariadb --restart=Never --rm=true --command -- mysql -uroot -ps3kr37 < dump.sql
```

and

```
kubectl exec mariadb-deployment-3614069618-mn524 -i -t -- mysql -u root -p=s3kr37 < dump.sql
```

But neither commands worked -- errors about TTY, sockets, and other things hinting that I am missing something vital here.

*What am I not understanding here?*

I *could* just stop the deployment, scp the database files, and restart the container and hope for the best. However, what can go right?

---

The question [Install an sql dump file to a docker container with mariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40925822/232794) sure looks like a duplicate but is not: first, I am on Linux not Windows and more importantly the answers all are about initialising with a dump. I want to be able to trash the data and revert to the dump data. This is a test system that will eventually be the "live" so I need to restore from many potential dumps.

Comment: What about mounting NFS into container with your database and then import dump in regular way like locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was this:

- Create an NFS mount with two sub0drectories: `mysql` and `initd`.
- In `initd`, I added several `,sql` files, including the dump.
- Mount `initd` as `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in the deployment.This causes all the files to be read at initialisation time *provided that it is the first time we run*.
- The `mysql` directory is mounted as `/var/lib/mysql` and contains all the mariaDB files.

If I need to revert, I trash all the contents of the `mysql` directory and re-create the deployment.

Answer (score 5):

As described in [here](https://medium.com/@madushagunasekara/export-mysql-db-dump-from-kubernetes-pod-and-restore-mysql-db-on-kubernetes-pod-6f4ecc6b5a64) you can use the following command to restore a DB on kubernetes pod from a dump in your machine

```
$ kubectl exec -it {{podName}} -n {{namespace}} -- mysql -u {{dbUser}} -p{{password}} {{DatabaseName}} < <scriptName>.sql
Example :
$ kubectl exec -it mysql-58 -n sql -- mysql -u root -proot USERS < dump_all.sql
```

Comment: @Affy This is restoring, not backup

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
kubectl  --kubeconfig=k8s-XXXXXXX-kubeconfig.yaml exec -i ddevdb-XXXXX -- mysql -u root -h mysqlservice -proot drupal < you-dump.sql
```

kubeconfig is optional, digitalocean for examples provides that so you can run your commands from your local.

To see if everything looks good:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=k8s-XXXXXXX-kubeconfig.yaml run -it --rm --image=mariadb:10.4 --restart=Never mysql -- mysql -h mysqlservice -proot
```

After which you'll have a terminal inside mysql.