# Google Kubernetes Engine mysql dump at midnight

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, backup, google-kubernetes-engine

I was wondering if I am to pesimistic, I cannot search or why are there so few information about how to (for example) dump an mysql db and access this dump from GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) mysql container?

Of course the basic idea is to have an CronJob running which creates the dump, no problem so far. But how can I access the PV?

The alternative of accessing the PV would be an SCP upload to one custome server, but I cannot believe that this is the best way?

(Mysql is just an example here, I also have an minio container, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about `mysql` - there is a wide article how to use mysql dump on new gke cluster.

https://medium.com/@pczarkowski/live-migrate-from-vm-based-mysql-to-kubernetes-based-mysql-48c8dab9ec3e

However you can use [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44777180/9929015) provided by @Sardathrion