# Want to dump data.sql file through dep.yaml file, don't want to go manual through bin/bash

Tags: mysql, git, kubernetes, volume, minikube

**1. I Want to dump data file using YAML file**

data.sql file in the volume

the YAML file is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
        volumes:
        - name: mydir
          hostPath: 
            path: /var/local/test
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
        - name: myfile
          hostPath:
            path: /var/local/test/data.sql
            type: FileOrCreate 

        containers:
        - image: mysql:5.6
          name: mysql
          env:
            # Use secret in real usage
        
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: root
          - name: MYSQL_USERNAME
            value: root
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            value: root
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: sample  
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
          - name: mydir
            mountPath: /var/local/test/data.sql
          command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
          args: ["mysql -u root -proot sample < data.sql"]
```

using a command, args concept but not possible

If I access the pod it can be dump easily but I want dump action through YAML

**2. Restore the database file in local system **

Also want to restore the dumped aur new data in my system or any other location but it will be accessible

Don't share the bash option
kubectl exec -it mysql-598cbfc789-2jlt7 -- mysql -u root -proot sample < data.sql

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you can't do this in the way you describe.  Kubernetes YAML isn't great for describing imperative actions like "restore a database dump".  If you need to do it there, you need to do it in a Job separate from the database proper.

The most portable way to do this is to not attempt it in Kubernetes YAML at all (so remove, for example, the override `command:` and `args:` in your Deployment).  Run `kubectl apply -f ...` as normal, and once the database comes up, run in two separate terminal windows

```
kubectl port-forward service/mysql 12345:3306
mysql -u root -proot -H127.0.0.1 -P12345 sample < data.sql
```

The first establishes a connection to the running database; the second uses the local `mysql` tool and your local filesystem, connecting to the forwarded port.  12345 can be any port number but needs to be the same in both commands.

Some other alternatives (focusing on `kubectl exec`) are described in [How do I restore a dump file from mysqldump using kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716207/how-do-i-restore-a-dump-file-from-mysqldump-using-kubernetes).

There are a couple of conceptual issues with the layout you show.  The first is that a container runs only one command, and your `sh -c 'mysql ...'` runs *instead of* the MySQL daemon.  A Kubernetes Pod also can't access your local filesystem, and if you use a `hostPath` volume like you show, you need to correctly guess which node the pod will run on and copy the data there; this isn't reliable and can lead to inconsistent results if you run it from different places.

---

If you can get the dump data into Kubernetes somehow, you can run a separate [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) to do the restore:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: mysql-restore
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql-restore
          env: { same as in: the question }
          image: mysql:5.6
          volumeMounts: { ... }
          command: [sh, -c]
          args:
            - >-
                mysql sample < /var/local/test/data.sql
```

The question is what to put in the `volumeMounts:`.  If the database dump is fairly small, you might be able to fit it into a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) and then [mount the ConfigMap into the Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume), but creating the ConfigMap can be awkward and the size is limited to 1 MB.  If you have a way to directly access the volume content (maybe you're mounting an NFS mount you can also access out-of-cluster) then you can copy the dump there.  You also might be able to use network-accessible cloud storage like Amazon S3 or another HTTP-based service where you can `curl` the dump at startup time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

- But this approach is not working

- For a minute if we talk about 2nd part
-In which, I want MYSQL data in any accessible location
as for backup 
-What kind of approach we can follow to clone that SQL data